# Can I blur the border of a div? CSS

Tags: css, border

I want the color of my box to be very opaque in the middle and then to fade out as it gets closer to the border.

Comment: There is a big difference between blur and transparency. Which of them are you looking for?

Comment: I don't really know which one is the right word to use but I'm looking to do something like this: https://placenamehere.com/objects/blog/blur-shadow.blur.png if that helps. I just want the color of the box to fade out if that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `box-shadow` for this purpose.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow?v=b

```css
body {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  background: royalblue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px navy;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

## Update:

After seeing a picture of what you were looking for, I tried to better match that.  Still with `box-shadow`.

```css
body {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  background: #999999;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10vw 2.5vw white;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```